# Gazebo Fortress - EntityComponentManager failing to create component when running in a docker image. Something I'm missing in my docker build?

Tags: gazebo

I've been building some code to do reinforcement learning on robots in a ros-gazebo environment, using ros2 humble and (ignition) gazebo fortress. My code is running fine on my machine, but when I build a docker image to run it on the university computing cluster I'm receiving the following error:

```
...
[Err] [EntityComponentManager.cc:1026] Failed to create component of type [9436740692853731264] for entity [58]. Type has not been properly registered.
[Err] [EntityComponentManager.cc:1026] Failed to create component of type [9436740692853731264] for entity [59]. Type has not been properly registered.
[Err] [EntityComponentManager.cc:1026] Failed to create component of type [9436740692853731264] for entity [60]. Type has not been properly registered.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM ros:humble-ros-base-jammy

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip wget
RUN wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ignition-fortress
RUN apt-get install -y ros-humble-ros-gz

RUN pip install tensorflow
```

Could there be some dependency missing from my image?

One relevant thing may be that I'm running programatically gazebo using the following code:

```
#include "simulation.hh"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ignition/gazebo/ServerConfig.hh>
#include <ignition/gazebo/Server.hh>

using namespace ignition::gazebo;

void Simulation::start() {
    ServerConfig config;
    config.SetSdfFile(_sdfPath);
    _server = new Server(config);
};

void Simulation::step() {
    if(_server)
        _server->RunOnce(false);
    else 
        throw std::runtime_error("Simulation not started: call start first!");
};
```

Starting gazebo in the docker container using the console seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've got it working now. Doesn't really answer why it wasn't working, but it was taking the version of gazebo fortress installed by ros-gz rather than the one I installed directly. Building it from source and making sure my code is using that version fixed my issue.